# Possible to use the slice operator with the aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, slice, aggregation-framework

I have a list of employees, each who belong to a department and a company.

An employee also has a salary history. The last value is their current salary.

Example:

```
{
  name: "Programmer 1"
  employee_id: 1,
  dept_id: 1,
  company_id: 1,
  salary: [50000,50100,50200]
},
{
  name: "Programmer 2"
  employee_id: 2,
  dept_id: 1,
  company_id: 1,
  salary: [50000,50200,50300]
},
{
  name: "Manager"
  employee_id: 3,
  dept_id: 2,
  company_id: 1,
  salary: [60000,60500,61000]
},
{
  name: "Contractor (different company)"
  employee_id: 4,
  dept_id: 1,
  company_id: 2,
  salary: [60000,60500,75000]
}
```

I want to find the current average salary for employees, grouped by dept_id and company_id.

Something like:

```
db.employees.aggregate(
  { $project : { employee_id: 1, dept_id: 1, company_id: 1, salaries: 1}}, 
  { $unwind : "$salaries" }, 
  {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "dept_id" : "$dept_id",
            "company_id" : "$company_id",
        },
        current_salary_avg : { $avg : "$salaries.last()" }
    }
  }
);
```

In this case it would be

Company 1, Group 1: 50250

Company 1, Group 2: 61000

Company 2, Group 1: 75000

I've seen examples doing something similar with $unwind, but I'm struggling with getting the last value of salary.  Is $slice the correct operator in this case, and if so how do I use it with project?

Comment: Without sort you could get the last of anything, you need a sort even with slice to get the last value you think your gonna get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to set up your pipeline as follows :

1. unwind the salary list to get all the salaries for each employee
2. group by employee, dept and company and get the last salary
3. group by dept and company and get the average salary

The code for this aggregation pipeline is  :

```
use test;

db.employees.aggregate( [
    {$unwind : "$salary"},
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "dept_id" : "$dept_id",
                "company_id" : "$company_id",
                "employee_id" : "$employee_id",
            },
            "salary" : {$last: "$salary"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "company_id" : "$_id.company_id",
                "dept_id" : "$_id.dept_id",
            },
            "current_salary_avg" : {$avg: "$salary"}
        }
    },
    {$sort : 
     {
         "_id.company_id" : 1,
         "_id.dept_id" : 1,
     }
    },

]);
```

Assuming that you have imported the data with:

```
mongoimport --drop  -d test -c employees <<EOF
{  name: "Programmer 1",                    employee_id: 1,  dept_id: 1,  company_id: 1,  salary: [50000,50100,50200]}
{  name: "Programmer 2",                    employee_id: 2,  dept_id: 1,  company_id: 1,  salary: [50000,50200,50300]}
{  name: "Manager",                         employee_id: 3,  dept_id: 2,  company_id: 1,  salary: [60000,60500,61000]}
{  name: "Contractor (different company)",  employee_id: 4,  dept_id: 1,  company_id: 2,  salary: [60000,60500,75000]} 
EOF
```

Comment: Perfect.  The step 2 grouping was what I was missing.  Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Although it might be simpler if you changed the data to have a single salary scalar and a salary_history array.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use [$slice in aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_slice). To return elements from either the start or end of the array: `{ $slice: [ <array>, <n> ] }`
To return elements from the specified position in the array: `{ $slice: [ <array>, <position>, <n> ] }`.

And a couple of examples from the mongo page:

```
{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 1, 1 ] }   // [ 2 ]
{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], -2 ] }     // [ 2, 3 ]
{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 15, 2 ] }  // [  ]
{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], -15, 2 ] } // [ 1, 2 ]
```